# Could a thermostatic shower cause pipe fittings to break?

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak, plumbing-fixture

I live in an apartment that has an in-wall (concealed type) thermostatic shower. Within the last year, we had two major water leaks caused by pipe fittings that connect to the shower box bursting open (see picture below). This happened once for hot water and once for cold.

[image: the connector that broke]

The fact that this happened twice makes me think this was not a coincidence. I have two theories as to what might have caused this, and I would like to hear what others have to say.

### 1. Bad design (?) of the thermostatic valve, causing severe water hammer

The shower is called Grohtherm Smartcontrol, pictured below.

[image: the shower system I have]

The shower system has a pushbutton to start and stop the water flow. The flow is quite strong even at its lowest setting, so when you're turning off the shower, you're always doing it with relatively strong flow.

In addition, the button operates in a very binary fashion, meaning it stops water flow after it's pushed beyond a certain point and it does so very abruptly.

I believe that all of this results in severe water hammer each time water is shut off. I once tried connecting a manometer under a sink nearby and I observed the manometer getting maxed out at 10bar when shower was turned off.

However, I'm not convinced that this is enough to cause the connectors to burst. After all, there are likely thousands of shower systems like mine and I find it hard to believe that the issues I'm seeing are solely a result of the way this unit is designed. I was also unable to find anyone referencing similar issues online.

This brings me to my next point.

### Bad plumbing job (or defective parts?)

I had the plumber who installed the shower system fix the two leaks that happened afterward.

When I asked him about what caused it, he said this was likely a defective fitting that was unable to withstand the stress of water hammer.

However, after the first leak, he replaced fittings with different ones and he did it for both the cold and hot water lines. Unfortunately, this did not prevent another leak a couple of months later. He blamed it on water hammer again and suggested I install water hammer arrestors.

I'm not a plumber and I'm not sure what might cause issues like these, but it seems like something is off when this happened twice already.

Could it be an incorrect type or an overtightened fitting? Could the parts be defective?

What would you do to make sure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Leaning towards the second idea, but might be for all those reasons adding up instead just one.  Over tightening can lead to stress cracks,  defective/less well made parts than in the past parts might lead to stress cracks being worst.  Add in water hammer and boom.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll only get opinions here since we can't examine the site and do a forensic  analysis.

Comment: The spliting of the fitting indicates to me that there is a mismatch of threads. Is is possible that one set of threads is tapered and the other parallel? Could the pitch be different? It looks like hemp fiber was used to seal the joint. Is this normal where this is or did the plumber resort to this to seal mismatched fittings?

Comment: I will go with defective,or cheap & weak, parts and possible overtightening. Most will overtighten things just because they don’t understand what parts actually make the seal.

Comment: Excessive water pressure could cause this. If you are in a multi-unit apartment you might want to see if others in the building are having similar issues. A normal safe range for water pressure is about 60 to 75 psi. It's possible a pressure regulating valve has gone bad. However, if so, you mighr see the problem on other fittings as well.

Comment: Water pressure is roughly 55psi, which is within the operating range of all plumbing fixtures and devices in our apartment. Our neighbors a couple of floors down had a similar problem with their bathroom faucet, but it is definitely not prevalent.

Comment: I would go with a bad seal and over tightened. Two tight can cut a Hose seal and will break the threads it looks like a gorilla was really tearing that apart.